# uBlox LEA 6H and UNO no data

Tags: arduino-mega, tinygps, gps

While using NEO 6M and getting close-to-perfect accuracy, connecting the 3dr uBlox LEA 6H shows incoming characters, but gibberish data (at 38400) like it is connecting to a wrong baud rate (although it isn't, i've checked it with u-center and works when connected to Ardupilot).
So i guess it is some kind of configuration to show only certain parts of NMEA (if it is showing NMEA and not something else).

Comment: what accuracy does your ublox lea6h gps have? I want to control quadcopter and need to find 1 GPS module has the high accuracy( may be < 1m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uBlox LEA 6H is most likly configured to use the UBX binary protocol and not NMEA at all. This protocol, as well as how to switch your LEA 6H between NMEA and UBX is in this document, from the uBlox website:
http://www.u-blox.com/images/downloads/Product_Docs/u-blox6_ReceiverDescriptionProtocolSpec_%28GPS.G6-SW-10018%29.pdf

You may be able to use the code from the ArduPilotMega project to communicate in UBX, they use the UBX protocol and the code is open source, but I can't guarantee its very good quality.

Comment: Using u-center, i'll try to change the output sentences. This pdf is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the ublox lea6H GPS to read either through NMEA protocol or the UBX protocol. You just need to send some configuration messages. For good data rate it is better to use UBX protocol as it gives data in binary format inducing less delay.In case you need to test your device you can use my GPS code for arduino mega - customized ardupilot gps code  - UBX protocol.

https://github.com/ksskarthik/Team_Pushpak/blob/master/TP_GPS